# Laravel 4 - php mail function does not work in server

Tags: php, email, laravel

I am using Laravel 4.3. I looked at PHP tutorial to send email like

```
$to = "tekobaya@xxx.com";
$headers = "From: psaf@xxx.com";
$subject = "this is a test";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

when I use this in local (http://localhost:8080), it send email. However, when I put codes to server, it does not send email. How can I use php mail function in server. Please advice.

Comment: you check if you have smtp or your mail transported enable and instablled on your server ?